# How to use query without using request.GET?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Im work with django framework i had an little problem

this is my urls.py

```
....
url(r'some/$' view, name)
....
```

how to use url with in
http://url.com/path?q=some&s=ds (and some long query)

if i use request.GET in view.py, it's so DRY

Answer (score 0):

You should use named groups:

```
url(r'page/(?P<page_slug>[\w-]+)$' view, name)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: if use thats regex in the url will be like page/3 but I want the url like page?slug=some-cool-slug